# Refresh DbContext

Tags: entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I have created a project that uses Entity Framework 6. This project is a data layer that is used in multiple other projects, for example an MVC website and a Web API.
When a user changes something in the MVC website, it is stored through the data layer in the database. But the Web API project does not detect these changes.

My DbContext is injected in the controllers with Ninject. I tried Disposing the DbContext in the controller's `Dispose` method, which didn't work. Should I `Refresh()` the database context after it has been injected in the controller's constructor? Or is there another way to keep the DbContext in sync with the database?

Fwiw, here is the OWIN Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);

        config.DependencyResolver = new NinjectResolver(NinjectWebCommon.CreateKernel());

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

And here is the Ninject code:

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon
{
    public static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new WebApiContrib.IoC.Ninject.NinjectResolver(kernel);

        // Register Services:
        kernel.Bind<MyDbContext>().To<MyDbContext>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("disableOrgFilter", true);

        return kernel;
    }
}
```